# Migrating Delphi5 components from Win2000 to Win7(64bit)

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-5

Firstly I can't really update the version because I would have to re-write my software which uses the dated components.

I initially had alot of success by re-installing the packages (around 40) to the fresh D5 install on the new Win7 machine. If it told me the .Bpl file was missing it works when I move it to the directory:

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Borland\Delphi5\Projects\Bpl

and similarly if the .dcu is missing I move it to the Delphi5\lib directory.

However my next obstacle is when I load any form which has an Advantage table (all of my software uses Adt files and AdsConnections). It gives me the error:

```
TableX.StoreActive : property does not exist
```

for many tables and a few more properties including LoginPrompt.

It seems these are not included in my components which were included on my previous installation. I've tried updating to the most recent version of Delphi Sp1 but cannot find any information on how to add these properties.

Comment: This is not the proper way to install components when you reinstall the IDE (or install for the first time on a new machine or operating system). Installing the components is much more than just copying DCUs and BPL files; it's configuring the environment, adding them to the proper parts of the registry, registering them with the IDE, and so forth. Stop now before you waste any more time (and make any more of a mess), and start over by properly installing the IDE. I'd suggest somewhere outside the `Program Files` tree (like in `C:\Borland` or `C:\Delphi`, for instance), to avoid access issues.

Comment: Assuming that most components won't remove properties in newer versions, this means the version of the bpl and dcu's you used on your old machine is more recent than the ones you have so far installed into the IDE of your new machine. Safe yourself a lot of hassle and do as @KenWhite suggests!

Comment: @KenWhite, that could be worth adding as an answer.  Maybe worth expanding a little to explain how to install components properly?

Comment: I'm trying my best Ken, thanks for explaining how I might properly install the IDE. I just followed the instructions. I've added the relevant paths and I don't seem to have any access issues with Program Files. As well as properties not existing it's telling me some components are not present on the form. Noticeably with my Advantage tables and AceReporter Export. I think it's either this or my Delphi version.

Answer (score 2):

I've carried out a similar migration: several projects developed in Delphi 5 on XP were moved to Windows 7. Unlike you, I also updated to Delphi 2010 at the same time.

The biggest difficulty I had was the lack of unicode support in my Delphi 5 components - I had to edit a lot of third party code. Of course, if I'd not upgraded to Delphi 2010 I wouldn't have needed to do that. Everything else went swimmingly. Here's how I did it.

First I made a copy of the project on the old machine, went through each form and replaced each of the third-party VCLs with run-time creation. It's a slog writing code to assign all the properties and events, but when I was finished there were only standard Delphi components on my forms but the project still ran correctly. Then I was able to move the project and the third-party .pas files to the new machine, open the project in Delphi 2010 and deal with the unicode issues.

The process was gruelling but straightforward.

Since then I've migrated another older project down the same path, but this time built a new application framework in Delphi 2010 and copied the units across piecemeal. In some cases I used the original .pas and .dfm files, in others I created new forms and copied the functional code. In all these cases I installed into Delphi 2010 the latest equivalents of the original third party components. This took a little longer than the original method.

However you tackle this, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @SourceMaid I'm hoping it's possible to avoid upgrading to 2010 as it may be a little beyond my ability. I just hope it's actually possible to get all these components on to Win7. My Delphi About is telling me it's Win2000 despite installing updates, which could be the problem. That or I've installed slightly older components for AceReporter and AdSDataSet.